# Altium: Script to add all symbols to a schematic?

Tags: altium, script

Does somebody knows a script which puts all the symbols in a library ([optional]: with every footprint added to it) to a schematic?

Would be handy to look over libraries, but unfortunately Altium don't know Python (yet).

Comment: A totally hacky first shot, was good enough for the usecase, basically just copied two examples together.

https://gist.github.com/morgulbrut/5adb56092da166cc61be8b0b69ab8422

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this would be a desirable feature because it would lead to a huge mess in most cases, and would be a very niche requirement. If you really want a script to do this, you might want to look into writing your own using Pascal, DelphiScript, EnableBasic, VB Script, or JavaScript. These are the languages Altium recognizes. You can find a guide on scripting at the following link:

https://techdocs.altium.com/display/SCRT/Scripting

I cannot seem to find an updated version, which suggests that the above page is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

click Design -> Make Integrated Library.

This will transfer all Schematic components (Symbol + Footprint) from all the libs you used into one INT LIB. For example: I used in one project parts from the Altium Vault, a company hosted Vault, an SVNDB lib from a different Project and an INTlib from another project.

After Design -> Make Integrated Library I have all used items in one lib and can modify them in the way I need.

The link to the origional lib is lost and you don't get updates from there. Depending on the project phase this can be an advantage or disadvantage.

Comment: Just asking: did you even read my question?

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your question. My answer is for the other way round. (Schematic ->lib)